# Why does /trigger have no objectives/commands after installing a datapack that has /trigger commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

***Disclaimer: I know this is similar to a previous question I asked that is related to this issue, but it was a bit too specific, and I've decided to ask a more general/focused question this time in the hopes of getting a concise/working answer.***

I recently noticed that a major issue arises when trying to use datapacks from the website Vanilla Tweaks (a website that hosts a multitude of datapacks that add small changes to the normal minecraft vanilla experience, hence the name - they're mostly rather small datapacks that **aren't game-changing - more like plugins rather than mods**.) on a specific 1.14 world (what I mean is not one specific world, but rather a world that has unique modifiers to it - in this case, it was converted from 1 version to another).

I didn't want to make the title any more confusing, but I still wanted to address that this is **not** a normal 1.14 world ("normal" meaning any sort of world that was created while playing in vanilla 1.14 and nothing else), but rather has these modifiers:

- The world was created in vanilla 1.8.9. (meaning this would be a "normal" 1.8.9 world, in a sense)
- No world settings were changed, other than setting the default gamemode to Creative Mode (which automatically enabled cheats) and changing the seed (normal world type, no additional changes).
- The seed used was "StackExchange" (just as a test seed). Numerical seed is 655809707.
- After creating the world, the world was converted to minecraft version 1.14.4 (vanilla) with no other alterations. (this was done by saving/quitting the world, relogging with ver. vanilla 1.14.4, and then joining into the world again)

After doing this, I then installed a datapack that required a /trigger command to use (essentially forcing the player to do /trigger [objective in datapack] in order to actually enable the datapack and/or toggle settings), and when entering /trigger, there were no objectives listed.

The datapack was recognized by minecraft itself, as it was shown in /datapack list.

I know that this was not supposed to happen, as after making a normal 1.14 world and applying the exact same settings and the exact same datapack, the /trigger command for the specific datapack was working perfectly fine.

I had also converted a world from 1.12.2 to 1.14.4, and /trigger commands were also working fine.

So, I can only think that there is some issue that occurs when converting a 1.8 world into 1.13 or higher (since it wasn't working for 1.14, I can assume that it would also not work for 1.13). My question is, **is there a way to fix this issue on a world that was already converted from 1.8 to 1.13+?**

It might be nice to also know a way to prevent this issue from occuring before converting a world, but I already have a rather-developed world that has this issue (which was converted from 1.8 to 1.14), and I hopefully want to find a way to make it so I can still use datapacks on that world. Thank you, and I appreciate any help I can get!

Link to VanillaTweaks datapacks (datapack I used was Coordinates HUD, for 1.14): https://vanillatweaks.net/picker/datapacks/

The world before converting to 1.14.4 (world version - 1.8.9): https://www.mediafire.com/file/8p1emc348isw0v6/file

The world after converting to 1.14.4, includes mentioned datapack (world version - 1.14.4): https://www.mediafire.com/file/jr2z8mcgywlx80v/file

Comment: If more information is needed or if I need to supply images, please let me know and I'll add them.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure all the trigger objectives are all enabled.  I also suggest reinstalling the datapack.  This may fix it but to know I would have to have your world.  I hope this helps.